# write an expression composed from car and cdr that will return c from the list '(a (b c) (d))

Tags: scheme, racket

write an expression composed from car and cdr that will return  c from the list `'(a (b c) (d))`.

I am using program called Dr Racket

I tried

```
(car (car (car (cdr '(a (b c) (d))))))
```

to get c by it self but it does not work.

The error states:

```
mcar: contract violation
expected: mpair?
given: b
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a small error in your code: Notice that you need the second element of the second element (which is an inner list) in the outer list. Your code is stating: retrieve the first element of the first element of the second element of the list:

```
(car (car (car (cdr '(a (b c) (d))))))
```

... Which causes an error. What you intended was this:

```
(car (cdr (car (cdr '(a (b c) (d))))))
```

Let's look at it step by step:

```
(cdr '(a (b c) (d))) ; => '((b c) (d)) : rest of the outer list
(car (cdr '(a (b c) (d)))) ; =>  '(b c) : second element of the outer list
(cdr (car (cdr '(a (b c) (d))))) ; => '(c) : rest of the inner list
(car (cdr (car (cdr '(a (b c) (d)))))) ; => 'c : second element of the inner list
```

Comment: Okay, help me look at it step by step please. I am willing to learn.

Comment: Oh so cdr looks at the last element while car looks at the first. Awesome!

Comment: @Genius2k13 more precisely, `cdr` looks at the rest of the list - the list that is after the first element. In a simple list, `cdr` returns a list and `car` returns an element

Comment: @Genius2k13 If the answer was useful for you please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the check mark to its left

Answer (score 1):

```
(cadadr '(a (b c) (d)))
```

`cadadr` is syntactic sugar for `(car (cdr (car (cdr ...)))`

Comment: This is correct, of course, but AFAIK OP specifies that only `car` and `cdr` can be used

Comment: (car (cdr (car (cdr '(a (b c) (d))))))

Comment: Pedantically speaking, `cadadr` is a function, not syntax, so `cadadr` is **functional sugar** for `(car (cdr (car (cdr ...))))` ;-P